# Failed to connect port 80 connection refused

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, nl-classifier

I am new to IBM Bluemix Watson application development. I developed a Natural Language Classifier application while uploading training data in classifier through cURL.

I am getting the following error:

[image: Failed to connect to port 80]

Answer (score 1):

The curl message that you initially received would normally indicate the host that you were trying to connect to in the error message, such as "...failed to connect to foo.bar.com port 80...", so I suspect that there is a problem in quoting or escaping quotes in your arguments to the curl command. Please double-check those - or paste your actual curl command in a subsequent comment (not a screen shot ;-), and I (or someone) can take a look at it.